# How to query PDF in Solr?

Tags: java, pdf, lucene, solr

I added PDF document to Solr

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=doc2&captureAttr=true&defaultField=text&fmap.div=foo_t&capture=div"  -F "tutorial=@a.pdf"
```

and I would like to query it for word "errors"

http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=errors&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on

I get no results.

However if I query it for word "java" I get one page(the added PDF text) and in visible text there is word "errors".

P.S. Im new to Lucene and Solr and I dont understand why not every word in that pdf is searchable.

Comment: Try extractOnly=true to see what Solr is extracting from the PDF.